# Program to find the the smallest three numbers in C

Tags: c

How I can modify my code in order to find the smallest three numbers.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a[50],size,i,small;

    printf("\nEnter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("\nEnter %d elements in to the array: ", size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);


    small=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
      if(small>a[i])
        small=a[i];
    }
    printf("Smallest element: %d",small);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in C++?

Comment: Because it's C tagged as C++.

Comment: Are you trying to find three numbers, which are smallest amongst all???

Comment: And as you're not dynamically allocating your array if the user enter a `size`greater than 50 you're just violating the memory. Use `malloc()` or limit the entered `size` to 50.

Comment: @deb_rider Yes, exactly

Comment: sort the array (most of the sorting code is in the Standard C library), then print the first 3 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial sorting of the array would always solve the problem easily.
If you don't want to implement sorting you can use this logic:

```
a=b=c=32767;
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(x[i]<a){
        c=b;
        b=a;
        a=x[i];
    }
    else if(x[i]<b){
        c=b;
        b=x[i];
    }
    else if(x[i]<c){
        c=x[i];
    }
}
printf("three smallest elements: %d, %d, %d",a,b,c);
```

Hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

```
/* store the three smallest in a[0],a[1] and a[2]. */

void place_three_smallest(int* a, int i1, int i2, int i3)
{
    a[0] = std::min(i1,std::min(i2,i3));
    a[2] = std::max(i1,std::max(i2,i3));
    a[1] = i1+i2+i3-a[0]-a[2];
}

// ...   
place_three_smallest(a, a[0], a[1], a[2]);
int ii = 3;
for(i=1; i<size; i++) {
    if (a[i] < a[2]) {
        place_three_smallest(a,a[0],a[1],a[i]);
    }
}

/* the first 3 elements of a are the smallest three, in order for least to most */
return a;
```

Comment: This is probably be better if the place function was:
    
    if (i2 < i1) SWAP(i1,i2);
    if (i3 < i1) SWAP(i1,i3);
    if (i2 > i3) SWAP(i2,i3);
    a[0] = i1; a[1] = i2; a[2] = i3;